# Replace part of URL in a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace a part of a button URL in a data attribute.

I'm trying to do it like this:
`$(elem).data('reditcontroller').replace('&id=', '&id=' + id);`

But the data attribute of the button (*elem*) stays the same.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.
I've also tried direct assignment using `=` and still not getting the expected result.

Comment: You need to assign the value back to the attribute!! `$(elem).data('reditcontroller', $(elem).data('reditcontroller').replace('&id=', '&id=' + id));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value back to the attribute!!

```js
$(function() {
  var id = "test1";

  $('#elem').attr('data-reditcontroller', $('#elem').attr('data-reditcontroller').replace('&id=', '&id=' + id));

  console.log($('#elem').attr('data-reditcontroller'));
});
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 25px;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="elem" data-reditcontroller="&id=">
</div>
```

Comment: It does execute and even with no errors but the data just won't update, don't know why

Comment: Have you tried this `$(elem).data('reditcontroller', $(elem).data('reditcontroller').replace('&id=', '&id=' + id));` ?

Comment: @CodePuppe - Use *.attr()* instead `$(elem).attr('data-reditcontroller', $(elem).attr('data-reditcontroller').replace('&id=', '&id=' + id));`

Comment: Eventually it worked but pretty weird. It does update the id value. However, the data attribute string does not changes at all but the request goes to controller with this id value anyway. Somehow works...still weird though that I can't see any changes and the programme can.

Answer (score 0):

This just calculates the new url. You should set it back to the button like this:

```
var newData = $(elem).data('reditcontroller').replace('&id=', '&id=' + id);
$(elem).data('reditcontroller', newData);
```